# aplicar función a diferentes campos

Tags: html, jquery

Cordial saludo, quiero poder aplicar la operación y redondeo que realizan las funciones`restar_entradas`y`restar_entradas2();` sin tener que declarar mas de una función, es decir, que con una sola función se aplique este proceso a varios campos. estuve revisando con el método addEventListener pero no pude realizarlo.

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).on('ready', constructor);
function constructor()
{
    function restar_entradas();
    function restar_entradas2(); 
}

function restar_entradas()
{
    $('#contenido').on('change', '#CALI_VERIFICAR1, #PATRON1', function(){
        var num1 = parseFloat($('#CALI_VERIFICAR1').val());
        var num2 = parseFloat ($('#PATRON1').val());
        var total = (num1 - num2);       
        var resultado = Math.round(total*100)/100;
        $('#DIFERENCIA1').val(resultado);

        if(isNan(num1))//Con esto quiero poder hacer que si no hay numero lo tome como 0 y no me muestre Nan, pero no funciona
        {
            num1=0;
        }

        if(isNan(num2))//Con esto quiero poder hacer que si no hay numero lo tome como 0 y no me muestre Nan, pero no funciona
        {
           num2=0;
        }
    })
}

function restar_entradas2()
{
    $('#contenido').on('change', '#CALI_VERIFICAR2, #PATRON2', function(){
        var num1 = parseFloat($('#CALI_VERIFICAR2').val());
        var num2 = parseFloat ($('#PATRON2').val());
        var total = (num1 - num2);       
        var resultado = Math.round(total*100)/100;
        $('#DIFERENCIA2').val(resultado);

        if(isNan(num1))//Con esto quiero poder hacer que si no hay numero lo tome como 0 y no me muestre Nan, pero no funciona
        {
            num1=0;
        }

        if(isNan(num2))//Con esto quiero poder hacer que si no hay numero lo tome como 0 y no me muestre Nan, pero no funciona
        {
           num2=0;
        }
    })
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="contenido">
<td><input type="text" name="PATRON1" id="PATRON1" value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" name="CALI_VERIFICAR1" id="CALI_VERIFICAR1"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="DIFERENCIA1" id="DIFERENCIA1"></td>

<td><input type="text" name="PATRON2" id="PATRON2" value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" name="CALI_VERIFICAR2" id="CALI_VERIFICAR2"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="DIFERENCIA2" id="DIFERENCIA2"></td>
</table>
```

Comment: Quien es #contenido? un input, un select, un radio o que?

Comment: es el nombre de la tabla, ya lo edite

Comment: El evento debería ejecutarse únicamente cuando cambie el valor de CALI_VERIFICAR1 y CALI_VERIFICAR2 no? no entiendo por que seleccionas también PATRON1 y PATRON2 en el change

Comment: Si lo dices por el valor de PATRON1 a veces puede cambiar, ya edito la pregunta.

Comment: Tienes un error de sintaxis aquí: `$function constructor()`.. deberías ponerlo sin el dólar.

Comment: En Nan hay error tambien, mi duda es que las dos funciones hacen cosas diferentes.Entonces como piensas controlar eso?

Comment: la idea es que hagan lo mismo, las mismas funciones en campos diferentes

Comment: ¿Te sale algún mensaje de error en la consola de depuración de javascript?

Comment: si,  "Uncaught ReferenceError: isNan is not defined"

Comment: @AnderssonViveros tienes otros dos errores de sintaxis en: `function restar_entradas(); function restar_entradas2();`. No se puede usar `function` para llamar una función, sólo para definirla. El segundo es la función que estás tratando de usar, se llama `isNaN` y no `isNan`, por eso te aparece "isNan is not defined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

realmente tu código se podía mejorar mucho:

1. No era necesario agregar una función por cada selector que estabas haciendo, y luego llamarla en el `ready`, todo esto se puede omitir.
2. En esta línea tienes dos errores de sintaxis:

   ```
   $function constructor(){
       function restar_entradas();
       function restar_entradas2(); 
   }
   ```

El primero es el signo **$** antes de `function`, el segundo es el `;` al final de cada línea donde estás intentando ejecutar las otras funciones, ¿Por qué? por que al agregar la palabra reservada `function` el sistema va a creer que vas a declarar una función nueva por lo cual no espera un `;`....recuerda que para ejecutar una función ya declarada basta únicamente con copiar su nombre seguido de () por ej: `restar_entradas();`

3. Ahora para hacer tu función dinámica sin importar la cantidad de campos tendríamos que editar un poco la estructura de tu tabla y agregar `<tr>` (de todas formas esa es la estructura que debe tener una tabla).

**Ejemplo funcional**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contenido').on('change', '.patron, .verificar', function(){
        var num1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('.verificar').val() == '' ? 0 : $(this).closest('tr').find('.verificar').val();
        var num2 = $(this).closest('tr').find('.patron').val() == '' ? 0 : $(this).closest('tr').find('.patron').val();

        var total = (parseFloat(num1) - parseFloat(num2));
        var resultado = Math.round(total*100)/100;
        
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.diferencia').val(resultado);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="contenido">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="PATRON1" id="PATRON1" value="14,2" class="patron"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="CALI_VERIFICAR1" id="CALI_VERIFICAR1" class="verificar"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="DIFERENCIA1" id="DIFERENCIA1" class="diferencia"></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="PATRON2" id="PATRON2" value="14,2" class="patron"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="CALI_VERIFICAR2" id="CALI_VERIFICAR2" class="verificar"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="DIFERENCIA2" id="DIFERENCIA2" class="diferencia"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una solución posible. Es mucho más sencilla que tu código, y le he intercalado comentarios que explican algunas particularidades, pero si tienes alguna duda pregúntame.

```js
$(document).on('ready', constructor);
function constructor()
{
  /**
   * Sin necesidad de funciones extra, aplicamos este evento a todos
   * los inputs que no sean 'readonly' (asumo que no quieres que
   * nadie edite manualmente los cmapos "DIFERENCIA", así que he
   * añadido ese tag al html
   */
  $('#contenido input:not([readonly])').change( function (e) {
    // Lo otro que he añadido al html es un campo "data-id", 
    // con valor 1 ó 2 dependiendo de a qué grupo pertenezca.
    // No es la única forma de hacerlo, pero es práctica y fácil.
    let id = $(this).data('id'); 
    if(!id) return; // Prevención de errores
    
    let num1 = parseFloat( $('#CALI_VERIFICAR'+id).val() );
    let num2 = parseFloat( $('#PATRON'+id).val() );
    var resultado = Math.round((num2-num1)*100)/100 || 0; // El "||0" final viene a decir que si resultado evalúa falso, entonces 0.
    $('#DIFERENCIA'+id).val(resultado);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="contenido">
<td><input type="text" name="PATRON1" id="PATRON1" value="" data-id=1></td>
<td><input type="text" name="CALI_VERIFICAR1" id="CALI_VERIFICAR1" data-id=1></td>
<td><input type="text" name="DIFERENCIA1" id="DIFERENCIA1" readonly></td>

<td><input type="text" name="PATRON2" id="PATRON2" value="" data-id=2></td>
<td><input type="text" name="CALI_VERIFICAR2" id="CALI_VERIFICAR2" data-id=2></td>
<td><input type="text" name="DIFERENCIA2" id="DIFERENCIA2" readonly></td>
</table>
```